# I lost one of my Toyota axio 2015 smart keys. How can I create a duplicate using the other key?

Tags: toyota, key, corolla, smartkey

How can I create a duplicate using the other key?

Comment: Are you just trying to mate a new key to the car?

Comment: Not a new key, I want to make another key by using the existing key.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is you can't. A new key needs to be purchased and programmed at the dealer. There is no simple way around this.